# How can I convert an iPad only app into a Univeral app?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, universal

I recently wrote an iPad app that I would like to make a universal app.

What is the best way to do this? Can I simply create two versions of my XIB files and load the  appropriate XIB based upon the device?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should help you out a lot:
http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2010/04/converting-iphone-apps-to-universal.html

Yes, you can create 2 xib files for every screen (one for iPad, and one for iPhone/iPod).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you do need 2 .xib files for every screen.   The tutorial that NeilMonday posted is helpful, but I found this one to be better:  http://www.raywenderlich.com/1111/how-to-port-an-iphone-application-to-the-ipad